# telerik RadSocialShare control unable to read content of a restricted page

Tags: telerik

I am using RadSocialShare facebook button to share a page on facebook. User should login to access this page. If I use this page URL to share in RadSocialShare, facebook is unable to read the content from this page and it shares the content from the login page. Is there a way I can share restricted page's some contents on facebook/google+/twitter etc?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, Facebook send a separate request to index the page and thus such hidden pages are hidden from its crawler. See here: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/socialshare-controlling-content-for-facebook.html.